# TinyMCE issues after upgrading to wicket 7

Tags: internet-explorer, tinymce, wicket, modal-window

I am having problems with TinyMCE in Internet Explorer after upgrading to Wicket 7. I have TinyMCE on a Modal Window, sometimes it is not editable when I open my modal window. Another frustrating thing is that this problem is intermittent, sometimes it works sometimes it does not. When I have my Developer tool open it works all the time.

This problem happens on Internet Explorer, it doesn't happen on Firefox and other browsers I have tried. When it happens and I check on my developer tool, I find "SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error".

Any kind of help will be appreciated, I have been on this for two days already.

Comment: Similar issues reported on TimyMCE: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/ourumb-dev-forum/bugs/49739-TinyMCE-and-Internet-Explorer http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-4630

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the problem was not TinyMCE but rather with the wicket ModalWindow getShowJavaScript method.

The older versions that works used, that is wicket 6.16.0:

```
protected CharSequence getShowJavaScript() {
return "Wicket.Window.create(settings).show();\n";
}
```

And the newer version that does not work uses, that is wicket 7.0.0:

```
protected CharSequence getShowJavaScript() {
return "window.setTimeout(function(){\n" + " Wicket.Window.create(settings).show();\n"
+ "}, 0);\n";}
```

As a solution, we created a new ModalWindow and called it TinyMCEModalWindow(it can be called anything I suppose) that overrides the getShowJavaScript method and use the older implementation.

Thanks for the assistance.